# Leaflet.markercluster: slow performance when zooming

Tags: leaflet, angular-leaflet-directive, leaflet.markercluster

I am rendering a million geojson data which is the type of Polygon.
This gives better performance when render the data.
But when zooming the map, gives very slow performance.

How to avoid this issue?

I am using the events zoomstart and zoomend to show the spinner.

This is starting after 6 or 8 seconds.
After zooming started, Leaflet.markercluster takes nearly 30 seconds to 1 minutes to complete the zooming.

My Anuglar Directive code:

```
    (function () {
        'use strict';
        angular.module('leafLet', [])
        .factory('leafLetService', function () {
            var leafLetService = {};
            return leafLetService;
        })
            .directive('leafLet', ['leafLetService', '$timeout', function (leafLetService, $timeout) {
                return {
                    restrict: 'AE',
                    scope: {
                        item: '=leafLet',
                        options: '=?options',
                        events: '=?events',
                        sharingValue: '=?sharingValue'
                    },
                    link: function (scope, $element, attrs, ngModel) {
                        var map = null, myLayer = null;
                        scope.events = scope.events || {};
                        scope.options = {
                            center: null,
                            zoom: null
                        };
                        scope.events.addData = addData;
                        var markers = null;
                        var element = document.getElementById(attrs.attrId);
/**Create a map object**/
                        function createMap() {
                            $(document).ready(function () {
                                $timeout(function () {
                                    map = L.map(attrs.attrId);

                                    var tiles = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                                        attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                                    }).addTo(map);

                                    createLayer();
                                    if (scope.events && typeof scope.events['mapCreated'] === "function") {
                                        scope.events['mapCreated']();
                                    }
                                    $(element).hide();
                                }, 0);
                            });

                        }

/**Create the layer and add to the map**/
                        function createLayer() {
                            myLayer = L.geoJSON().addTo(map);
                        }

/**Bind zooming detection for the map**/
                        function onZooming() {
                            map.on("zoomstart", function (e) {
                                map.spin(true);
                            });
                            map.on("zoomend", function (e) { map.spin(false); });
                        }

/**Add geojson data to the existing map. This will help to add data partially to the map**/
                        function addData(geoJsonData) {
                            //myLayer.addData(data);
                            $(element).show();
                            markers = markers || L.markerClusterGroup();

                            var geoJsonLayer = L.geoJson(geoJsonData);
                            markers.addLayer(geoJsonLayer);

                            map.addLayer(markers);
                            map.eachLayer(function (layer) {
                                if (!layer.on) return;

                                layer.on('loading', function (event) {
                                    map.spin(true);
                                });

                                layer.on('load', function (event) {
                                    map.spin(false);
                                });
                            }, this);
                            map.fitBounds(markers.getBounds());

                            onZooming();

                        }

/**Initial function to be called**/
                        function init() {
                            createMap();
                        }

/**Initial function calling.**/
                        init();
                    }
                };
            }]);

    }());
```

[image]

Comment: Your screenshot does not show any cluster? what are you using for individual markers?

Comment: I have uploaded the code that I have done. Please see the code.

Comment: I am using the type of Polygon data. That's y i think getting like this.

Comment: Polygons are not clustered with Leaflet.markercluster plugin.

Comment: Then How do I overcome the zooming issue?

Comment: First try canvas instead of SVG. Then consider showing less data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143165/discussion-between-jeeva-jsb-and-ghybs).

Comment: That's a lot of data. Why not try using mapbox vector tiles? They will be much faster and you can implement clustering